# Does NServiceBus design follow Topic-based publish/subscribe pattern?

Tags: nservicebus, esb, publish-subscribe

I am little bit confused on design pattern followed by NServiceBus(ESB). Is it truly Topic-based publish/subscribe design pattern?

Answer (score 3):

NServiceBus supports many message-exchange patterns, include publish/subscribe. Since NServiceBus supports multiple queuing infrastructures, the way that publish/subscribe is implemented on each one may be slightly different.

For example, on broker-style middleware like RabbitMQ, NServiceBus does indeed leverage topic-based routing. On MSMQ, which doesn't support topics, NServiceBus reverts to point-to-point routing when developers invoke `Bus.Publish(message)`.